# Inheritance in 'Extension Builder' ext of TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-tca

I want to develop an extension, I have an entity `FamilyMember` and sub-entities `Child` and `Conjoint`. `Child` and `Conjoint` extends `FamilyMember`. This is a description for my UML conception, but the problem that I don't know how to implement this with builder extension, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Extension Builder allows you to extend only models from existing **AND** installed extensions, so while creating new ext you can't do that, theoreticaly...

You have two ways:

1. Create `FamilyMember` (and other required models) but not `Child` and `Conjot`, save it, install new extension, back to Extension Builder and add these two - you will have there a field called `Extend existing model class`.
2. Probably faster: Create all models in `Extension Builder` as *standalone* after saving just edit PHP classes for these models and change extending from `Tx_Extbase_DomainObject_AbstractEntity` to your other class